# Laravel 8 artisan serve

Tags: laravel-8

When I run my app (laravel 8, jetstream, tailwind ...) on `php artisan serve` all is working as expected. If I try to access the app over `http://localhost/dev/myapp/public` I get an error `Undefined array key 0`. How to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel should life in the root of you domain, therefore there is [`php artisan serve` command](https://laravel.com/docs/master/releases#artisan-serve-improvements) for local development.

If you really want to access the project otherwise, you have to make several [adjustments](https://medium.com/backenders-club/how-to-host-a-laravel-project-on-a-shared-hosting-via-cpanel-d955d32c528e) but this is not recommend for local development.